# Selection Field Customisation in UITabBar

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I need to customise the UITabBar as shown in this image, for my project. Is it possible to do so? And if so, how can it be done? the selection field should have this "orange" shade[image: Tab Bar. Selected Field Must have Color]

Comment: Please see my answer below and let me know if it works. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  You can find the answer to this question with a very easy Google search, but even if you couldn't we would need you to first say what you had tried (and failed) to do for this question to be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing :

```
yourTabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];
```

Create the orange gradient as an image and use it in the code above.

Hope this helps.